# How do I correctly handle multiple capturing groups in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get:

`example.com/curriculum/<curriculum name>/unit/<unit name>/`

to rewrite to:

`example.com/curriculum/unit/?c=<curriculum name>&u=<unit name>`

so far I have:

```
RewriteRule ^/curriculum/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/unit/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ https://www.example.com/curriculum/unit/?c=$1&u=$2
```

Considering that:

```
RewriteRule ^curriculum/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ https://www.example.com/curriculum/?c=$1
```

works as expected, I assume my syntax is off, as when loading, I just get error 404, with the URL not rewritten from its original format. To clarify, /curriculum/unit does exist.

Any guidance or advice on what I need to do to make this work? Thanks!

**Update**

Full .htaccess file as requested:

```
### activate mod_expires
ExpiresActive On

### Expire .gif's 1 month from when they're accessed
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
### Expire everything else 1 day from when it's last modified
### (this uses the Alternative syntax)
ExpiresDefault "modification plus 1 day"

### Apply a Cache-Control header to index.html and styles.css

###Cross-Site Scripting protection
Header always set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"

###Disallow websites to frame legacycars - user protection
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    #No Cache browser revalidates on each request and fetches new version IF contents change based on ETag or Last-Modified response
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|php)$">    
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
    </FilesMatch>

    #DAY Stock and Cover images expire at the end of each day, but must be checked for changes
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg)$">    
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>

    #WEEK Icons and badges expire after a week
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|png|gif|swf|svg|xml)$">    
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    #MONTH Site framework expires after a month, but must be checked for changes
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|json)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>

    #Hide .credentials
    <FilesMatch ".credentials.php">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/error/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 https:/www.example.com/error/403.html

# Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On

#Rewrite curriculum and unit to GET vars
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^curriculum/([\w-]+)/unit/([\w-]+)/?$ curriculum/unit/?c=$1&u=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
    RewriteRule ^curriculum/([\w-]+)/?$ curriculum/?c=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Externally redirect direct client requests for subdomain-subdirectory URLs
# to subdomain URLs without subdomain-subdirectory URL-path

    Redirect permanent /sd_manage/ https://manage.example.com

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^manage(.*)$ https://manage.example.com [R=301,L] 
    RewriteRule ^manage/(.*)$ https://manage.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite root subdomain to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Rewrite valid subdomains to the secure site
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www|manage)\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may keep these 2 rewrite rules:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews        
RewriteEngine On

# Externally redirect direct client requests for subdomain-subdirectory URLs
# to subdomain URLs without subdomain-subdirectory URL-path
RewriteRule ^sd_manage/ https://manage.example.com [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^manage(/.*)?$ https://manage.example.com$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# Rewrite root subdomain to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Rewrite valid subdomains to the secure site
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

#Rewrite curriculum and unit to GET vars
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^curriculum/([\w-]+)/?$ curriculum/?c=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^curriculum/([\w-]+)/unit/([\w-]+)/?$ curriculum/unit/?c=$1&u=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, no. The curriculum/something works, but curriculum/something/unit/something-else still goes to curriculum/something instead of curriculum/unit. Not sure how to approach this

Comment: yes. /unit is contained within /curriculum. So it’s curriculum/unit. The idea is each index page in each directory then wants to pull the GET variable ?c and ?u to determine what to show on the page, but there is one real index page for all curriculums, and one real index page for all units, structured as /curriculum: {/unit: {index.php}, index.php}

Comment: I have provided full code starting from `ErrorDocument` lines to last rule. Replace all of your code below `Options` line with this code and retest.

Comment: Thank you! That works! Do you know off the top of your head what the issue was?

Comment: I believe ordering of rules was the the main problem.